# Render fonts with freetype

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, freetype

I made opengl rendering engine, and i can render shapes, 3d shapesand textures. Then i wanted to render fonts. I used freetype library to do this. But i have one serious problem with it. When i render font it looks terrible. First i will explain how i initialized freetype, and loaded font, then how i render textures, so you will be able to see itf there are any mistakes.

1. I initialize freetype and load font like this:

   ```
   FT_Library  library;
   FT_Face     face;
   FT_GlyphSlot  slot;

   FT_Init_FreeType(&library);
   FT_New_Face(library, "arial.ttf", 0, &face);
   FT_Set_Char_Size(face, 0, 20 * 64, 300, 300);
   slot = face->glyph;
   FT_Load_Char(face, 'a', FT_LOAD_RENDER);
   ```
2. Then i load it into my texture:

   ```
   this->tex.LoadFromBuffer(slot->bitmap.buffer, slot->bitmap.width, slot->bitmap.rows);
   ```

   The tex object is just texture container which looks like this:

   ```
   class Texture
   {
   public:
       void LoadFromBuffer(unsigned char* buf, int w, int h);
       float sizex, sizey;
       GLuint texName;
   };
   ```
3. And load from buffer function looks like this:

   ```
   void Texture::LoadFromBuffer(unsigned char* buf, int w, int h)
   {
       this->sizex = w;
       this->sizey = h;

       glGenTextures(1, &this->texName);

       glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->texName);

       glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
       glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

       glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
       glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);

       glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

       stbi_image_free(buf);
   }
   ```

   Then texture is created and i render it just normaly with opengl on squad:

   ```
   void Renderer::Render(Quad& quadv)
   {
       glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
       glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);
       glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, quadv.texture->texName);

       glBegin(GL_QUADS);

       glColor3f(quadv.color.r, quadv.color.g, quadv.color.b);
       glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);   glVertex2f(quadv.vertices[0].x, quadv.vertices[0].y);
       glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);   glVertex2f(quadv.vertices[1].x, quadv.vertices[1].y);
       glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);   glVertex2f(quadv.vertices[2].x, quadv.vertices[2].y);
       glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);   glVertex2f(quadv.vertices[3].x, quadv.vertices[3].y);

       glEnd();

       glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
   }
   ```

   Quadv is object which contains vertices of quad, but its not important here.
   Texture in quadv is the texture with letter a, that i loaded before.

Code looks just normal to me, but when i run it, the texture looks like this:

[image]

A letter is triple no matter what size texture is or size of quad.
And whole image is terrible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recall what is the default PixelMode when using FT.
But it looks to me like you are assuming that the bitmap provided by FT comes as a 32-bit RGBA color, which is probably not the case.

I'm gonna assume it comes as an 8-bit color. Try changing:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);
```

to

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);
```

We replaced `GL_RGB` which was the input format to `GL_RED` such that the tex image function expects 1 component per pixel. [FT2 Documentation](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-basic_types.html#ft_bitmap) for further information

Comment: Thank you a lot, now it looks better. Now there is just one letter in quad and it fills up whole quad. But letter color is now red, any idea how can i change it to black? And the background around letter is black too for some reason.

Comment: The command you now issues is telling opengl that the texture you are creating has four components.
R G B A, but you're only giving it R as input.
To be honest I am not sure what the default values of G B A will be then.
But a solution is to modify your shader to only read the R value from the texture and use it as alpha.

Eg:

    float intensity = texture2D(Texture, Uvs).r;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, intensity);

Comment: I had a look through the documentation of opengl

GL_RED
    Each element is a single red component. The GL converts it to floating point and assembles it into an RGBA element by attaching 0 for green and blue, and 1 for alpha. Each component is clamped to the range [0,1].

Comment: *"gonna assume it comes as an 8-bit color"* This is not very reliable. You have to actually check what format you get (usually either 1 or 8 bits per pixel),.

Answer (score 0):

The bitmap contains 1 channel per pixel, encoded in a single byte. Since you're using legacy OpenGL, I recommend using the internal texture format `GL_ALPHA`. Therefore each element of the texture is treated as a single alpha component.

<s>`glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);`</s>

```cpp
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_ALPHA, w, h, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);
```

Enable [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending) to show only the opaque part of the glyphs:

```cpp
void Renderer::Render(Quad& quadv)
{
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, quadv.texture->texName);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glColor3f(quadv.color.r, quadv.color.g, quadv.color.b);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);   glVertex2f(quadv.vertices[0].x, quadv.vertices[0].y);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);   glVertex2f(quadv.vertices[1].x, quadv.vertices[1].y);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);   glVertex2f(quadv.vertices[2].x, quadv.vertices[2].y);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);   glVertex2f(quadv.vertices[3].x, quadv.vertices[3].y);

    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```